# phpmyadmin localhost error (xampp)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am getting an error when I try to login to myphpadmin...

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

is there something wrong with my config file?

```
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '<username here>';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '<password here>';

/* Storage database and tables */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */
```

I couldnt help but notice that alot of this is committed out....should it be?

I really dont know what I am doing...any help would be amazing!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '<username here>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '<password here>';
```

Those two lines at the very least need to be configured, if you just did a base install either they're both blank or the username is root and the password is blank. If you assigned a user name and password they go in those fields, and since your allow no password is set to false then you need to set your DB up with a username and password or set that value to true. Having no password when testing locally is fine, NOT when you upload it to your live server though.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, this is what my config.inc.php file looks like:

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

If I go into phpMyAdmin and click the privileges tab I also have the following users:

```
User    Host    Password    Global privileges   Grant
Any     %         --        USAGE               No
Any     localhost No        USAGE               No
pma     localhost No        USAGE               No
root    127.0.0.1 No        ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes
root    localhost No        ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes
```

Comment: it helped but now I get this error when I log into phpmyadmin `The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated.` and I am unable to create a database (No Privileges) it says

Comment: I added to my post to include the users and permissions that they have in phpMyAdmin.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Delete all the related cookies after closing it all down,, then if that dont work check your php ini config file to see if user has been altered.

Comment: delete all the cookie on my browser?

Comment: This isn't going to do anything, as per my answer the reason is your'e passing the wrong username and password to the database. That should be sort of obvious by the error it's returning.